# Deploying a jar file and external resource files with Maven

Tags: java, maven, deployment, build

I am new to Maven and wanted to automate some build steps by automatically deploying several files and folders to the production environment:

```
my-app-0.7.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar (main application file)
conf.properties (configuration file that can be edited on the fly)
files_folder (folder that contains html, css etc. that can be edited on the fly)
```

My project structure look like this:

```
src
   main 
      java
      resources (contains resources that should be included in the .jar)
conf.properties.jar 
files_folder
```

.

I started by adding `<resources>` element in the `pom.xml`

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>.</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>conf.properties</include>
            <include>files_folder/**/*.*</include>
        </includes>
        <targetPath>..</targetPath>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

This moves `conf.properties` and `files_folder` to the `target` directory and this is fine (I can copy .jar, conf.properties and files_folder and run them).

However these files are not moved to the local repository in `C:\Users\my_name\.m2\...` or external repositories (in install and deploy phases).

My thinking is that these resource should be moved to the repositories because:

- they are necessary for the program to run
- it would be possible to rollback to any previous version very fast (just locate the version folder and everything you need would be there; it would not be so easy if conf.properties and files_folder would not be automatically included in there)

So the main questions are:

1. Is this line of thinking reasonable?
2. If it is reasonable, how is it possible to include these external resources in the repositories?

Comment: Maven is a build tool and not a deployment tool. For deployment to environments like Test, Q&A or Prod other tools are more suitable like Chef, Puppet or may be a simply shell script etc.

Comment: I understand that this could be the case. But in this particular situation does it really make sense to learn and use another tool for moving to a local repository two extra files or folders? The main reason for these actions would be to keep the history of all fully deploy-able versions somewhere.

Comment: You can of course create a separate maven project (combined into a maven multi module build) and put those configuration files there and may be use maven-assembly-plugin to package them into a zip file...Or create in the same module a zip file which contains the configuration files would work as well.

Comment: From this and other comments I am getting a feeling that Maven should not really be used for deploying to production environment or archiving all deployable versions even in this simple scenario. Considering the simple nature of the tasks, I will probably just create some powershell scripts for archiving deployable versions and moving them to production. Your first comment summarizes this best, so maybe you can create an answer from it that I can accept or I can create one myself later after implementing some kind of scripting solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven is a build tool and not a deployment tool. For deployment to environments like Test, Q&A or Prod other tools are more suitable like Chef, Puppet or may be a simply shell script etc

Answer (score 0):

Like other response I'd suggest you need to look at a continuous integration approach. I have had good experience working with Jenkins before. It's free, and comes with a lot of functionatlity. It also has a large community that have developed a range of plugins:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins

Depending on what you're deploying and how you want to deploy it some plugins that may be helpful to your process are:

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin
- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin
- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+FTP+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping this files in the classpath, you can keep these files at src/main/resources/META-INF. So when you build your project using maven and if you have chosen the packaging as ear 
    `<artifactId>ProjectName</artifactId>
    <version>Version</version>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>`
then all these files will be packaged inside the jar and will be available in your maven repository

Comment: I am not sure if this would include a "configuration file that can be edited on the fly".  I did not include these files in the .jar because I wanted to be able to edit them on the server (if it was necessary), but still provide default configuration.

Comment: In that case it is better to go with Jenkins(CI server) but there also it won't move those files to the maven repository.Even in Jenkins you need to create a maven based job and it works the same as in any IDE